# PRINT PDF using PCL AND PJL in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, printing, printer-control-language

we have some ricoh printers in our offices and we want to print from php using a simple socket but some documents are pre printed and are located in tray 2 the default sheets are in tray 1 . i want to be able to select a tray of that printer using a combination of the PJL PDF and PJL PCL language . anyone has an idea maybe? i've found this on the forum :

```
<ESC>%-12345X@PJL<CR><LF>
@PJL SET STAPLE=LEFTTOP<CR><LF>
@PJL    [... more PJL commands if required ...]
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PDF<CR><LF>
[... all bytes of the PDF file, starting with '%PDF-1.' ...]
[... all bytes of the PDF file ............................]
[... all bytes of the PDF file ............................]
[... all bytes of the PDF file, ending with '%%EOF' .......]
<ESC>%-12345X
```

it prints my pdf , however when i add the

```
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PCL<CR><LF>
<ESC>&l1H <CR><LF>
```

around that code . 
i get some strange results... 1 pdf splits up over 5 papers with nothing but stream data (weird signs).

so i did the following

```
<ESC>%-12345X@PJL<CR><LF>
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PCL<CR><LF>
<ESC>&l1H <CR><LF>
<ESC>%-12345X@PJL<CR><LF>
@PJL SET STAPLE=LEFTTOP<CR><LF>
@PJL    [... more PJL commands if required ...]
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PDF<CR><LF>
[... all bytes of the PDF file, starting with '%PDF-1.' ...]
[... all bytes of the PDF file ............................]
[... all bytes of the PDF file ............................]
[... all bytes of the PDF file, ending with '%%EOF' .......]
<ESC>%-12345X
```

however this printed the file from tray 1 again , it seems that it lost the settings when trying to print the pdf file ...

anyone got any tips for me or can make a correction? i think i'm nearly there ...

Comment: Which brand of printer is it? Because it depends on it. Canon: `@PJL COMMENT CANPJL SET STAPLE=ONEUPLEFT` RIcoh: `@PJL SET STAPLE=LEFTTOP`

Comment: Hi , i commented in the answer , it was a ricoh mp c3003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set paper type as workaround for tray selection:

> Not all printers with PDF Direct Print feature support the PJL mediasource instruction; e.g. Ricoh aficio printers do not.
>   After weeks of struggling, I finally managed to get hold of the Ricoh manuals relating to PJL instructions supported by Ricoh.
>   Ricoh supports the @PJL SET MEDIATYPE=SPECIAL – special is the paper as defined for a specific tray. You can assign a specific paper type for a tray, so requiring a specific paper results in using a specific tray. And provided the printer is properly configured (trays need to be set to “automatically selected”), this finally works.

Source: http://www.tachytelic.net/2010/10/hp-direct-pdf-printing-and-printer-tray-control/

I'm also interested in driverless printing using PJL to wrap pdf, and also working with Ricoh printers, plase keep me updated.
Wich Ricoh models are you working with ?

TIA

Comment: Yes that is the way i worked around this, we are using ricoh mp c3003  . Under the settings pane of the printer i added special paper type (with the paper settings ) on tray 2 and used @PJL SET MEDIATYPE=SPECIAL